# Add comma to values VBS

Tags: csv, vbscript

I'm wondering if it is possible to add a comma between values in VBscript so that it is formatted correctly in .csv files.

```
 Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
xmlDoc.Async = "False"
xmlDoc.Load ("C:\Users\c1921\Ayla_Data\TestFile.xml")

Set colNodes = xmlDoc.SelectNodes _
("/datapoints/datapoint/(updated-at | value)")

For Each objNode In colNodes


Wscript.Echo objNode.Text


Next
```

If `updated-at` is a time value and `value` is a data value then I would like one to be in column A and another in column B. Is this easily done?

I can't seem to find any references for how to do this. I'm wondering if something like this line might work(It gives me a syntax error):

```
Wscript.Echo & "," objNode.Text
```

**EDIT**

Going off of what Ekkehard.Horner said the amended code looks like this:

```
Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
xmlDoc.Async = "False"
xmlDoc.Load ("C:\Users\c1921\Ayla_Data\TestFile.xml")

Set colNodes = xmlDoc.SelectNodes _
("/datapoints/datapoint/(updated-at | value)")

mystringout = ""
mystringnext = False

For Each objNode In colNodes

If mystringnext= False then

mystringout = mystringout & objNode.Text & "," 

 mystringnext= True

Else

mystringout = mystringout & objNode.Text & vbCrLf
mystringnext = false


End If 

 Next

WScript.Echo mystringout
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use the concatenation operator correctly (x & y), or [Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yscc53h0%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) (which scales much better):

```
>> av = "ColAVal"
>> bv = "ColBVal"
>> WScript.Echo av & "," & bv
>> a = Array(av, bv)
>> WScript.Echo Join(a, ",")
>>
ColAVal,ColBVal
ColAVal,ColBVal
```

Comment: Thank you I couldn't get Join to work for me but I did use the corrected concatenation.